# Flume Avro sink to a Node.js server possible?

Tags: node.js, flume, avro

First-time Stack Overflow questioner here... will try to include as much detail as possible.

I'm trying to get Apache Flume log data transferred through an Avro sink to a Node.js server, listening on a particular port.  I intend to use [Collective Media's node-avro library](https://github.com/collectivemedia/node-avro) to help with serialization between Avro's binary format and JSON, so I can work with the data in Node.js (I'm passing it on to clients via [socket.io](http://socket.io) pub/sub).

I'm petty sure I have Flume configured correctly since I see the data flowing through the channel and output to the console (for debugging only, I have the data sinking out to console as well).  When I enable the Avro sink and bring up the Node.js server that listens on the same port, though, Flume throws an exception when it tries to do the Avro transfer:

```
2013-02-15 22:06:09,858 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Failed to send events
    at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.process(AvroSink.java:325)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: localhost, port: 4242 }: Failed to send batch
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.process(AvroSink.java:309)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: localhost, port: 4242 }: Exception thrown from remote handler
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.waitForStatusOK(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:318)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:295)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:224)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: NettyTransceiver closed
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.CallFuture.get(CallFuture.java:128)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.waitForStatusOK(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:310)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: NettyTransceiver closed
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.disconnect(NettyTransceiver.java:338)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.access$200(NettyTransceiver.java:59)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver$NettyClientAvroHandler.handleUpstream(NettyTransceiver.java:496)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:792)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:348)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:236)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:476)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:623)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:364)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:238)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
2013-02-15 22:06:14,895 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.createConnection(AvroSink.java:178)] Avro sink k1: Building RpcClient with hostname: 127.0.0.1, port: 4242
```

What I'm not sure about, is how to figure out if my Node.js service is at least getting the message.  I'm pretty new to Node.js so that doesn't help, but here's a snippet of the code that sets up the listener:

```
var flumeSink = require('http').createServer(flumeHandler);
flumeSink.listen(8000);
function flumeHandler (req, res) {
    console.log("Got it!");
    //var schema = avro.prepareSchema("string");
    //var buffer = schema.encode("foo");
    //var value = schema.decode(buffer);
}
```

I'm thinking I've set up the Node.js side wrong.  I'm using the HTTP module, which perhaps isn't the right module.  Maybe I need to consider writing a custom sink in Node.js?  Pointers/help appreciated!

Comment: Reading more on this, I see that Avro works through RPC, so I think the HTTP thing is indeed misguided.

Comment: Tried replacing the http listener with a dnode one, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the avro sink is not what you need in this case, as it was designed to communicate Flume to Flume (it's the way you build a Flume connected topology).

if you want to create a sink that is not on the standard list, you need to build a custom sink and use a custom configuration as defined in https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#custom-sink
this i tried and it works perfectly.

or use something that exists:

https://github.com/josealvarezmuguerza/flume-http-sink

i never used this module. just came by with a google search.

for the Avro part, just use morphlines to convert your source into avro and then post each event to your node.js server.

hope this gives a little light.

go code!